# ASP.NET MVC Initial Load taking 10 minutes

Tags: jit

I have a simple MVC web app with 4 controllers that behaves fine on one Windows 2008R2 server, but on two new servers, one 2008R2 and one Windows 2012, takes an extremely long time to do the initial JIT compile after publishing.

The normal server takes about 10 seconds to load after a new version is published, the other servers take about 10 minutes for the first page, and several minutes to load the first access of each controller. After the initial compile the pages load normally.

The app targets .Net 4.5 Any CPU Debug mode. The server that works and one of the 'bad' servers have identical .Net 4.6.1 installed, the other has 4.5.2. One of the 'bad' servers has .Net Core 1.0 installed. In ProcMon csc.exe shows up under the w3wp.exe for the 10 minutes, but takes 0% CPU for most of that time. No errors in event viewer. FileMon doesn't show any access errors.

What can cause this extremely slow compile? What else is there to check for the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by antivirus settings on the VMware host. Excluding the Temporary ASP.Net files folder from the antivirus scan solved the problem:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files